# Charging issues MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021)

Tags: usb, battery, thunderbolt, charging, power

Usually use my MBP with a [USB-C Digitial AV Multiport Adaptor](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter). Through this adaptor I connect my monitor via HDMI, connect a USB A hub and charge my MBP using the original charger.

Every few weeks/months something odd happens. When I disconnected the my MBP I first noticed that its battery was 68% which I gave not too much notice because I have 'Optimised battery charging' set in the System Preferences. But then I struck me that it should not have discharged below 80%.

Now I can not get the MBP to charge anymore. This is where I am now:

1. Dongle. Now when I try to charge the the MBP through the dongle it cycles through 'charging' 'not-charging', which feels disconcerting. Now, when I am writing this, the cycling stopped and it it not even charging anymore.

[image]

2. Direct USB-C charging using the original USB-C cable does nothing

[image]

3. Direct charging through the original MagSave power cable gives me an orange light but does not charge the laptop.

[image]

It feels like a battery/charging issue on the MBP.

[image]

A reboot, or a reboot with a SMC reset fixes this issue on the short term, but after ~4 weeks the issue is back again.

On the phone the Apple Genius advised to try a System re-install because of a possible faulty 'driver' (which sounds bananas to me with systems like 'Code Signing' and 'System Integrity Protection').

After a full System re-install the issue first seemed to be solved, but just this week I had 2 'not charging' issues. Re-installing does not seem to fix it.

My questions:

- Is this a known issue?
- Should I accept it, do a system re-install and move on?

See also: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh29198/mac

See also: https://overcast.fm/+B7NBmskGY/48:38 were Marco Arment talks about the same issues with Gruber on The Talk Show.

*ps. Got to stop typing before my battery is completely dead.*

Comment: If you have any hardware concerns about a machine that is less than 1 year old, there should be no hesitation about taking it to an Apple Store for diagnosis.

Comment: I am very OCD about extending my battery life, so I try to keep it plugged in at all times (and even connect power banks to slow down the rate of depletion when away from a wall socket), use [AlDente](https://apphousekitchen.com), etc. I've lost count of how many times my MacBook Pro exhibit similar issues to yours. Sometimes a reboot is all it takes to solve it -- and the issues appear to have subsided after replacing a partly broken USB-C cable. Once, one of my 4 USB-C inputs had all the symptoms of being fried, but an SMC/PRAM/NVRAM brought it back to life.

Comment: @swineone, Apple used to state that always connecting the device to a charger reduces battery life and they recommend to discharge at least one a month <https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1167201>. They do not talk about that anymore and it seems you can keep the device connected <https://www.apple.com/batteries/>.

Comment: @CousinCocaine I didn't want to veer the conversation away from the main topic, I just wanted to exemplify how excessively plugging and removing things leads to similar symptoms. Still, unhealthy amounts of research have led me to conclude, beyond any reasonable doubt, that keeping a laptop plugged in the majority of the time at 100% will result in much faster battery deterioration, versus keeping the battery at a lower SoC (say 80% or ideally 60%) using an utility such as Al Dente. Indeed Apple recommends discharging the battery to ~50% if stored for long periods.

Comment: Called apple, the genius advised to try a System re-install because of a possible faulty 'driver'. We will see. Updated the question accordingly.